# Save data from edit popup

Tags: javascript, input, edit, profile

I have a popup section with two inputs for stock values. My Expected result – typed name and description should show up in the profile section after saving.

I only want to use native JS and the id is restricted.

The issue is following - even if I type something in form inputs, input.values  remain the same as defined in the HTML.

```
    <section class="profile">
      <div class="profile__info">
        <img class="profile__avatar" src='./images/Cousteau.png' alt='Profile Image'>
        <div class="profile__data">
          <p class="profile__name">Name</p>
          <p class="profile__description">Description</p>
        </div>
        <button class="profile__edit-button"></button>
      </div>
      <button class="profile__add-button"></button>
    </section>


    <section class="popup popup_status_is-closed">
      <div class="popup__content">
        <button class="popup__close-button"></button>
        <h3 class="popup__title">Edit</h3>
        <form class="popup__form">
          <input class="popup__input popup__input_type_name" name="name" type="text" required minlength="2" maxlength="25" value="Name">
          <input class="popup__input popup__input_type_description" name="description" type="text" required minlength="2" maxlength="35" value="Description">
          <button class="popup__button" id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```

JS

```
    function formSubmitHandler(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      const nameInput = popUp.querySelector('.popup__input_type_name');
      const descrInput = popUp.querySelector('.popup__input_type_description');
      const profileName = profile.querySelector('.profile__name');
      const profileDescr = profile.querySelector('.profile__description');

      nameInput.value = profileName.textContent;
      descrInput.value = profileDescr.textContent;

      closeEditForm();
    };

    saveButton.addEventListener('click', formSubmitHandler);
    formElement.addEventListener('submit', formSubmitHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a number of issues with your code.

1) You have your assignment the wrong way around - i.e. `nameInput.value = profileName.textContent` should be `profileName.textContent = nameInput.value`

2) Your selectors are wrong - you want to select from `document` not from the undefined `popUp`, `profile`, etc

3) Your handler is wrong - you need to add the event handler to the submit button

4) I could be wrong but I think your inputs should have `placeholder` rather than `value` - that is `Name` and `Description` are simply to identify the type of input...

With all that in mind - I made some changes and this should be working as expected

```js
function qs(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function formSubmitHandler(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  qs('.profile__name').textContent = qs('.popup__input_type_name').value;
  qs('.profile__description').textContent = qs('.popup__input_type_description').value;
  closeEditForm();
}

function closeEditForm() {}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', formSubmitHandler);
```

```html
 <section class="profile">
   <div class="profile__info">
     <img class="profile__avatar" src='./images/Cousteau.png' alt='Profile Image'>
     <div class="profile__data">
       <p class="profile__name">Name</p>
       <p class="profile__description">Description</p>
     </div>
     <button class="profile__edit-button"></button>
   </div>
   <button class="profile__add-button"></button>
 </section>


 <section class="popup popup_status_is-closed">
   <div class="popup__content">
     <button class="popup__close-button"></button>
     <h3 class="popup__title">Edit</h3>
     <form class="popup__form">
       <input class="popup__input popup__input_type_name" name="name" type="text" required minlength="2" maxlength="25" placeholder="Name">
       <input class="popup__input popup__input_type_description" name="description" type="text" required minlength="2" maxlength="35" placeholder="Description">
       <button class="popup__button" id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About n. 2 I should say, that all used prefixes were defined in the beggining (sorry, I did not share full code). About n.4 unfortunately, it is supposed to be precisely "value" (but I also tried to deal with this by changing to placeholder).

Comment: @IxxyDev - does it work as you want? If so the usual thing to do is to accept the answer so that others can see you have a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I am on it. Accidentally pushed my comment before it was ready. I will surely accept the answer after trying out. Also thanks for your editing of original post. Really appreciate that.

Comment: No worries - you can run the example in the answer by hitting the "run code snippet" button at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you. I have already "relocated" the solution to my project and it worked well. Accepting)